# Python sorting dictionary

Tags: python

I want to sort the following **dictionary** by the keys `score`, which is an array.

```
student = {"name" : [["Peter"], ["May"], ["Sharon"]],
           "score" : [[1,5,3], [3,2,6], [5,9,2]]}
```

For a better representation:

```
Peter ---- [1,5,3]
May ---- [3,2,6]
Sharon ---- [5,9,2]
```

Here I want to use the **second element** of `score` to sort the `name` into a list.

The expected result is:

```
name_list = ("May ", "Peter", "Sharon")
```

I have tried to use

`sorted_x = sorted(student.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

and

```
for x in sorted(student, key=lambda k: k['score'][1]):
    name_list.append(x['name'])
```

but both dont work.

Comment: First off, that is not a valid dictionary initialization, second off, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Third, this seems like a pretty odd way to store this data.  It doesn't seem like you gain much from the dict in this case:  `name = [['Peter'], ['May'], ['Sharon']]` -- And you don't gain much from having a list of list either ... `name = ['Peter', 'May', 'Sharon']`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question.

Comment: @CLWONG -- Your opening `dict` still isn't valid python syntax.  Did you mean to use `:` where you have `=`?

Comment: Ops ya. Typo mistake. Thanks

Comment: @mgilson. Thanks for your reply. Originally, there are two separate array `name` and  `score`, but someone just combined them into a dictionary. Thats why I need to use a odd way to store the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First zip the students name and score use `zip`.

```
zip(student["name"], student["score"])
```

you will get better representation:

```
[(['May'], [3, 2, 6]), 
 (['Peter'], [1, 5, 3]), 
 (['Sharon'], [5, 9, 2])]
```

then sort this list and get the student name:

```
In [10]: [ i[0][0] for i in sorted(zip(student["name"], student["score"]), key=lambda x: x[1][1])]
Out[10]: ['May', 'Peter', 'Sharon']
```

Know about the sorted buildin function first: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Answer (score 1):

This would probably work for you:

```
student = {
    "name": [["Peter"], ["May"], ["Sharon"]],
    "score": [[1,5,3], [3,2,6], [5,9,2]]
}

# pair up the names and scores
# this gives one tuple for each student:
# the first item is their name as a 1-item list
# the second item is their list of scores
pairs = zip(student['name'], student['score'])

# sort the tuples by the second score:
pairs_sorted = sorted(
    pairs,
    key=lambda t: t[1][1]
)

# get the names, in order
names = [n[0] for n, s in pairs_sorted]

print names
# ['May', 'Peter', 'Sharon']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dictionaries, I suggest using `OrderedDict`:

```
name = ["Peter", "May", "Sharon"]
score = [[1,5,3], [3,2,6], [5,9,2]]
d = {n: s for (n, s) in zip(name, score)}

from collections import OrderedDict
ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][1]))
list(ordered)  # to retrieve the names
```

But, if not, the following would be a simpler approach:

```
name = ["Peter", "May", "Sharon"]
score = [[1,5,3], [3,2,6], [5,9,2]]
d = [(n, s) for (n, s) in zip(name, score)]

ordered = sorted(d, key=lambda t: t[1][1])
names_ordered = [item[0] for item in ordered]
```